# I am using Pandas for a sentiment analysis problem, I want to change my categories to ['Agree', 'Disagree', 'Neutral'] to a scale from 1 to 5

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sentiment-analysis

```
recsys_file = pd.read_csv('full_chat_questions.csv')

for elem in recsys_file["item3G_new"]:

    if recsys_file["elem"] == 'Strongly disagree':
         recsys_file['elem'].replace(to_replace = elem, value = 1)

    if recsys_file["elem"] == 'Disagree':
         recsys_file['elem'].replace(to_replace = elem, value = 2)

    if recsys_file["elem"] == 'Neutral':
         recsys_file['elem'].replace(to_replace = elem, value = 3)

    if recsys_file["elem"] == 'Agree':
         recsys_file['elem'].replace(to_replace = elem, value = 4)

    if recsys_file["elem"] == 'Strongly agree':
         recsys_file['elem'].replace(to_replace = elem, value = 5)
```

## trying to change the categories to values from 1 to 5 but I am getting errors

Comment: recsys_file["item3G_new"] is  0      Strongly disagree
1         Strongly agree
2      Strongly disagree
3      Strongly disagree
4               Disagree
             ...        
234    Strongly disagree
235    Strongly disagree
236             Disagree
237    Strongly disagree
238    Strongly disagree
Name: item3G_new, Length: 239, dtype: category
Categories (5, object): ['Agree', 'Disagree', 'Neutral', 'Strongly agree', 'Strongly disagree']

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it uses np.select() to make your code more concise and gives a default value if there is nothing matching (which might be part of the problem)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
recsys_file = pd.read_csv('full_chat_questions.csv')
condition_list = [recsys_file["elem"] == 'Strongly disagree', recsys_file["elem"] == 'Disagree', recsys_file["elem"] == 'Neutral', recsys_file["elem"] == 'Agree', recsys_file["elem"] == 'Strongly agree']
choice_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
recsys_file["elem"] = np.select(condition_list, choice_list, 0)
```

Comment: thank you a lot, I also tried this:  
'
recsys_file["item3G_new"].replace(to_replace=['Agree', 'Disagree', 'Neutral','Strongly agree', 'Strongly disagree' ], value=[1,2,3,4,5], inplace=True)
'

Comment: So was my solution the answer you were looking for?